# Create Notification on SharePoint List Item updated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I would like to create the email alert by informing particular user created the list item ,That specific column of list item is updated .

Can anyone help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

you can use out of the box solution with mixing `Alert Features` and `versioning` feature.

- `Alert Features` for notification.
- `versioning` to check what's changed.

Another solution is to create workflow `on item update` and send notification to `created by` user with the details of item updated but it needs more work to get old value and new value for specific column, you can also check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/238d45de-cf66-4268-85ec-d7b8f191c9af/how-to-tell-if-column-value-has-changed-for-use-in-workflow-actions?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

**The steps to use Alert :**

- In the list or library where the folder, file, or list item is located, select the item you want to create an alert for.

[image]

- On the New Alert page, in the Alert Title section, change the title for the alert if you want. The title appears in the subject line of the alert e-mail message.
- at Send Alerts To , enter the user names or email addresses of people you want alerts to be sent to.
- In the Delivery Method section, select the method of delivery you want for your alerts.
- Choose the types of changes that you want to be notified about. For example, you can receive alerts about all changes or only when items are modified.
- In the Send Alerts for These Changes section, specify whether you want to be alerted for all types of changes, or for specific changes, such as when anything changes or only when someone changes an item that you created or recently changed.
- In the When to Send Alerts section, choose how frequently you want to receive the alerts, such as immediately or in a daily or weekly summary, and at what day or time.

> NOTE:  For mobile (SMS) alerts, Send notification immediately is the
>   only option.

- Click OK.

[image]

Check also if [The “Alert Me” button is not visible on the ribbon in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/26/the-alert-me-button-is-not-visible-on-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint/)

**The steps to enable versioning**

- Open list settings > Versioning settings > adjust your versioning settings.

Comment: Can also use item updated event receiver to do this.

Comment: Yes , you are right @bkk and in this case, you will need to code your event receiver on item_updated event, but the above answer as OOTB solution if the user does not have experience without code meanwhile it's easy way, Thanks "bbk" for your comment